# como escribir parametros y que me retornen solo dos letras

Tags: string

Escribe una función que reciba dos strings (de largo > 2) como parámetros, y retorne un string de largo 4 que consista de las dos primeras letras del primer string y las últimas dos letras del segundo.

Por ejemplo, si los strings son "familia" y "abrigarse", entonces tu función debe retornar "fase".

```
def mezclador(string_a, string_b):
 
  return ?
```

Comment: Deberías darte una vuelta por [ask], editar y mostrar que has intentado

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Aqui no se hace los deberes a nadie. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código:

```
def mezclador(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) < 2 or len(str2) < 2:  # Si los string no son lo suficientemente largos
        return "Los string deben de ser de largo > 2"
    str_resultado = str1[0:2] + str2[-2:]
    return str_resultado


print(mezclador("familia", "abrigarse"))  # Llamamos a la funcion
```

Los [ ] son para obtener una parte específica de un string...

Checa esta página: https://programminghistorian.org/es/lecciones/manipular-cadenas-de-caracteres-en-python

Comment: enserio muchas gracias :)  me ayudaste mucho

Comment: Por favor leer [answer]. Gracias por responder, pero debemos evitar responder preguntas que no demuestran al menos algún intento. Eso es hacerle los deberes o tareas a otros y no es bien recibido. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, lo tendré en cuenta.